# Which IoC Container to use?

Tags: ioc-container

I'm in the process of choosing an IoC container to inject my application dependencies.

I have worked with Spring.NET. I have heard about Autofac, StructureMap and Microsoft Unity as well which are quite similar .

Which IoC container would you recommend to use and why?

Many thanks,

Comment: They all have their pros and cons. Ultimately it depends on what you require from the container and you haven't elaborated on that.

Comment: If you're familiar with Spring.NET, there is no reason to go with anything else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET IoC Container Comparisons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140730/net-ioc-container-comparisons)

Answer (score 2):

You could read about comparaisons. Look at that thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140730/net-ioc-container-comparisons

Answer (score 0):

> I have worked with Spring.NET. I have
>   heard about Autofac, StructureMap and
>   Microsoft Unity as well which are
>   quite similar .

It probably doesn't matter from a technical point of view.  As you say, they're quite similar.

Spring.NET does not come from Microsoft.   Stick with a Microsoft framework if using their full stack is important to you.

I've used the Java version of Spring for many years.  I think it's excellent.